# How e.printStackTrace result get printed inside logs

Tags: wildfly, printstacktrace

I am using wildfly and I am having no idea how all **e.printStackTrace** statement get printed in **server.log** file of **wildfly**.

What is the **configuration** behind that. Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

System.out and System.err are redefined to go to jboss logging.
Take a look at the JDK [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr-java.io.PrintStream-)